# OpenStack Grizzly keystoe remove_user command removing ALL users

Tags: openstack, grizzly, openstack-horizon

I have the following code that works great in Folsom:

```
#remove the user for each role associated with the user
    user_roles = kc.users.list_roles(obj_id, currtenant)
    for role in user_roles:
        if obj_id == user.id:
            kc.tenants.remove_user(currtenant, obj_id, role.id)
```

That same code will remove ALL users rather than just the user with the id, obj_id from the tenant specified.  anyone else have this issue in Grizzly?

Comment: For what it's worth, the grizzly tag, in this context, is not correct.

Comment: This is related to grizzly

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, it's a known issue with the Grizzly code base.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/keystone/+bug/1170649

The bug also includes the suggested fix.